# Define a filter on $\mathbb{N}$ for a given equivalence relation.

Tags: general-topology, logic, filters

> *Let $A$ be the set of all sequences $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ such
> that $x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Define the
> relation $\sim$ on $S $ as follows. For all $(x_n)_{n \in
> > \mathbb{N}},(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in S, (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\sim(y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$
> if and only if there exists a positive
> integer $k$ such that $x_n = y_n$ for all $n \in \{km : m \in \mathbb{N}\}.$
> Define a filter $\mathcal{F}$ on $\mathbb{N}$ such
> that for all $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}},(y_n)_{n \in\mathbb{N}}\in A,(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sim (y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$
> if and only if
> $\{n \in \mathbb{N} : x_n = y_n \} \in \mathcal{F}$.* 
>  *Further
> show that $\mathcal{F}$ is, or is  not, an ultrafilter on
> $\mathbb{N}$*

I have proven that $\sim$ is a equivalance relation. Then I attempted to define $\mathcal{F}$ as
$$ \mathcal{F} = \{F \subseteq \mathbb{N} : \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } x_n \in F, \forall n \ge N, n \in \mathbb{N} \}$$. But this is not correct and hence my reasoning for filter and ultrafilter parts were not correct. I have spent a lot of time on this problem and can't seem to come up with the solution. Any advice or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is actually asking you to verify that the $\mathcal F$ that it defines is a filter. And then check whether it's an ultrafilter.

Comment: @kahen You are expected to define the filter yourself, show that it is indeed a filter and that it satisfies the if and only if condition. Then show that it is not an ultrafilter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did $A$ become $S$ (and then back again) in the problem statement? Regardless, I'll write $S$ for the set of real valued sequences.

Given any $k\in\mathbb N$, write $k\mathbb N:=\{km:m\in\mathbb N\}$.

Given two sequences $\vec x,\vec y\in S$, write
$$
E(\vec x,\vec y):=\{n\in\mathbb N: x_n=y_n\}.
$$

Note that
$$
\vec x\sim \vec v \iff \exists k\in\mathbb N [k\mathbb N\subset E(\vec x,\vec y)]
$$

Let
$$
\mathcal F:=\{X\subset\mathbb N: \exists \vec x,\vec y\in S[\vec x\sim \vec y \wedge E(\vec x,\vec y)\subset X]\}.
$$
I claim that, given any two $\vec x,\vec y\in S$,
$$
\vec x\sim \vec y \iff E(\vec x,\vec y)\in\mathcal F.
$$
The forwards direction is immediate. To see the converse implication, suppose $E(\vec x,\vec y)\in \mathcal F$. This means that there exist $\vec u,\vec v\in S$ such that $\vec u\sim\vec v$ and $E(\vec u,\vec v)\subset E(\vec x,\vec y)$. Fix $k\in\mathbb N$ such that, $k\mathbb N\subset E(\vec u,\vec v)$. Then $k\mathbb N\subset E(\vec x,\vec y)$, so $\vec x\sim \vec y$.

Next step is to show that $\mathcal F$ is a filter. It is obviously upwards closed. Suppose $X,U\in\mathcal F$, say $E(\vec x,\vec y)\subset X$ and $E(\vec u,\vec v)\subset U$, and pick $k,l\in\mathbb N$ such that $k\mathbb N\subset E(\vec x,\vec y)$ and $l\mathbb N\subset E(\vec u,\vec v)$. Then
$$
lk\mathbb N\subset E(\vec x,\vec y)\cap E(\vec u,\vec v)\subset X\cap U
$$
Define two sequences $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ so that $a_n=0=b_n$ for $n\in lk\mathbb N$ and $a_n=1$ and $b_n=-1$ for $n\not\in lk\mathbb N$. Then $lk\mathbb N=E(\vec a,\vec b)$, so $\vec a\sim\vec b$ and $$E(\vec a,\vec b)=lk\mathbb N\subset X\cap U$$

But then $X\cap U\in\mathcal F$, and we're done showing that $\mathcal F$ is a filter.

---

If we look at what we just did, it emerges that the real sequences don't really matter, in the sense that the filter can be described without mentioning them:

$$
\mathcal F=\{X\subset \mathbb N: \exists k\in\mathbb N(k\mathbb N\subset X)\}
$$

Is this an ultrafilter?

> Every member of $\mathcal F$ is infinite, hence $\mathcal F$ is non-principal. But $\mathcal F$ doesn't contain every cofinite set.

Comment: So in essence it's the filter generated by the filter base $\{k\Bbb N\mid k \in \Bbb N\}$, in short. Being countably generated implies it's not a free ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yeah, I thought starting off with that might be slightly more obscure, hence my arguably overtly verbose answer.